# What is right way to get CurrentUser RegistryKey

Tags: c#, registry

Maybe that will be a stupid question, but what is the difference between

```
RegistryKey curUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
```

and

```
RegistryKey curUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);
```

Thanks.

Comment: None that jumps out, you'll have to [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that they are pretty much the same. `Registry.CurrentUser` is just a shortcut. 
Looking at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/src/Microsoft/Win32

You can see that `Registry.CurrentUser` is implemented like this:

```
RegistryKey.GetBaseKey(RegistryKey.HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
```

and `RegistryKey.GetBaseKey` like this:

```
internal static RegistryKey GetBaseKey(IntPtr hKey)
{
   return GetBaseKey(hKey, RegistryView.Default);
}
```

and `Registry.OpenBaseKey` uses `GetBaseKey` as well, like this:

```
public static RegistryKey OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, RegistryView view)
{
   ValidateKeyView(view);
   return GetBaseKey((IntPtr)((int)hKey), view);
}
```

I would assume that the `RegistryView.Default` does pretty much the same thing as your `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32`